# BuddyPress returning incorrect xprofile date

Tags: buddypress

It was all working fine but all of sudden BuddyPress xprofile `date` field giving one date before. However, I have checked in the database and the entry is correct. It is just returning the wrong date.

This means, If I set the date to 1920-12-12 it is storing the correct (the same) but returning 1920-12-11.

I am getting the date using the following BuddyPress function.

```
// tried by field id
bp_get_profile_field_data([
    'field'   => 5,
    'user_id' => 14
]);

// tried by field name
bp_get_profile_field_data([
    'field'   => 'Date Of Birth',
    'user_id' => 14
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot duplicate this issue.

The default BuddyPress xprofile `date` field only supports 1956 as the earliest year. 
Perhaps the issue lies with whatever code you are using to support years like 1920.

Comment: 1920 is just for reference. However, the users are not older thqn 40 years. The issue is not only when I get using bp_get_profike_field_data but it alsow showing day prior on memebers profile. Which is BP default template.